# How to save XML formatting settings in project and not workspace?

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting, settings

In Eclipse it is great that you can save many settings in a Eclipse project folder - mostly in .settings folder. But how can I do the same with XML editor settings?

Right now I cannot share the same settings for the whole team via a eclipse project, so every developer has his own preferred settings, which is a mess in bigger teams.

edit1:
found the corresponding issues, which are very old on eclipse.org https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248896 
so if you face the same issue, vote for getting the bugs/feature fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Only code which is designed to support project specific options can do this.

The WTP XML editor is not designed to do this so it is not possible.

Comment: do you have an idea where to post a feature request (or better a bug ;-) )?